# Why generics is used with class component in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was learning React with Typescript and as I wanted to create class component, it turns out that we need to use generics like this:

```
type MyProps = {
  // using `interface` is also ok
  message: string;
};
type MyState = {
  count: number; // like this
};
class App extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
  state: MyState = {
    // optional second annotation for better type inference
    count: 0,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.message} {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Ok, as my research says that generics helps to achieve re-usability , for example, when we create a function with generics like this:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

BUT what I cannot wrap my head around is that WHY do we need to use generics here `class App extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState>`?

Comment: If you didn't - how would you specify what are the types of the component state and its props?

Comment: @zerkms, No)) I just took that example from a certain resource, I just wanted to create class component but found that example which shows we need to use generics therefore I kindly want to ask WHY?)))

Comment: My comment partially answers it: so that you could specify the types of the component's state and props.

Comment: @zerkms, ok but why exactly via generics? can't we use class App extends React.Component and use types like this state: MyState. I am sure there is a reason behind that but cannot find that reason:)

Comment: Let's imagine it was the case: how would you declare the `setState` method of the `React.Component` class?

Comment: React Component by itself does not know what `message` or `count` are. Some classes have props, some don't. Others have state, some don't. You're defining the class' interface (definition so to speak) .

Comment: @Dom, so, should I consider generics as if class component's parameters? or...:)

Comment: Generics are type parameters. The same way you pass parameters to function when you invoke it, the generic types are instantiated when you pass type parameters into them.

Answer (score 1):

Re-use is not the primary concern here, even though `React.Component` is re-used in this scenario.

The generics serve a different purpose, namely to allow customization of the props and state members in a type-safe way. Keep in mind Typescript adds type safety on top of Javascript and hence class members etc. must be defined with types.

In your example, without your `MyState` type there's no information what the component should use for its state member and you will get an error when you use things like `this.state.count`. Typescript can only ensure correctness when it knows what is actually supposed to be there.

Side note: React itself has a mechanism to provide type safety, even without Typescript. You can find more information about [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) on the React homepage. But I would recommend Typescript any time over `PropTypes`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Component type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L444) specifies a lot of things, e.g. the signature of methods:

- `render(): ReactNode;`
- `constructor(props: Readonly<P>);`

Generics provide a way to specify which concrete props and state are allowed in the type definitions of all the methods.